# If the measure value is Blank, rather show the most recent value that will not make the measure Blank based on 2 different Dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want my measure to display a value and not a Blank, but currently, there are two Dates that are affecting my outcome. Calculation Date and my Percentile Date.

- Calculation Date is used for the overall report and it goes up until 09/02/2023
- Percentile Date is specifically used in that 75thpercentile_measure calculation and goes up until 01/01/2023

My goal is to create a measure that does not go, Blank, when the Calculation Date is higher than the Percentile Date it just shows Blank in the card, but would like it to instead of going blank rather show the value of the Most Recen Calcualtion Date which is = to the Percentile Date.

It will always show blank when the Calculation Date is higher than 01/01/2023 but when they are equal or Calculation Date is lower than Percentile Date it will show the percentage values of the given days.

Sample Value of 75thpercentile_measure: 8.88%

```
  Desired Output Measure = 
 IF(
    ISBLANK([75thpercentile_measure])
    ,CALCULATE(
         [75thpercentile_measure]
         ,overall_data[Calculation Date]=[Max Percentile Date Measure]
     )
    ,[75thpercentile_measure]
 )
```

If I still don't make any sense just comment below so I can clarify.

Comment: Try `LASTNONBLANK()`

Comment: Does not work, LastNonBlank wants a column, I am using a measure, in this case I get a Blank Measure when a specific date is selected in the Slicer cards